# Python 3.x - Attribute descriptor using setattr/getattr vs internal value

Tags: class, python-3.x, attributes, instance, descriptor

I am new to Python descriptors. The question below is to help me better understand how they work.

In Python 3.x, I am using an attribute descriptor. The particular thing about this descriptor it that its set method contains a lot of sanity checks to make sure the value about to be set to the attribute respects some rules. The constructor uses the setattr and getattr to manipulate the attribute. The constructor works well and its code is reported below.

```
class AttributeDescriptor():    <----- Version 001 of this class

   def __init__(self, attname):

      self.__attname = "__" + attname

   def __set__(self, obj, attvalue):   

       #Some data quality checks, not provided here...

      setattr(obj, self.__attname, attval)   

   def __get__(self, obj, owner):   

      return getattr(obj, self.__attname) 


class Hobbit():

   def __init__(self):

      pass

   name = AttributeDescriptor("name")

sam = Hobbit()
merry = Hobbit()

sam.name = "Sam"
merry.name = "Merry"

print(sam.name)        ----> Returns "Sam"
print(merry.name)      ----> Returns "Merry"
print(sam.name)        ----> Returns "Sam"
```

I also tried defining the constructor with the following code, which returned erroneous values for the "name" attribute. Indeed, all Hobbits names were set equal to the last name which had been defined.

```
class AttributeDescriptor():    <---- Version 002 of this class

   def __set__(self, obj, attvalue):   

       #Some data quality checks, not provided here...

      self.value = attvalue 

   def __get__(self, obj, owner):   

      return self.value  


class Hobbit():

   def __init__(self):

      pass

   name = AttributeDescriptor()

sam = Hobbit()
merry = Hobbit()

sam.name = "Sam"
merry.name = "Merry"

print(sam.name)        ----> Returned "Merry"
print(merry.name)      ----> Returned "Merry"
print(sam.name)        ----> Returned "Merry"
```

My question is: how come the descriptor Version 002 sets "name" equal to a common value through all its istances ?

From what I understand of descriptors, the descriptor Version 001 will store names in **an attribute** of the Person object instance:

```
sam.__name = "sam"
merry.__name = "merry"
```

while the descriptor Version 002 will store names in **an attribute of the attribute** of the Person object instance:

```
same.name.value = "sam"
merry.name.value = "merry"
```

Therefore, there is obviously something which I do not understand about how a Python descriptor works. Could anyone provide me with some clarifications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example your are setting the value on the AttributeDescriptor instance itself.

You have only one AttributeDescriptor() instance in your program and there for it changes the same value every time you get to his **set** method

class Hobbit():

```
  def __init__(self):

     pass

  name = AttributeDescriptor("name") # <---- happens ONLY once!!!
```

The class definition in python happens only* once ...

*unless it doesn't. But lets stick to the easier Truth :)

Comment: There we go ! I didn't know that. And it explains everything. Thanks. :)

Comment: Are the "name" attribute and the AttributeDescriptor instance the same thing or two different things ? Is the attribute "name" a different entity connected to another object of class "AttributeDescriptor" ? ... just trying to understand

Comment: What if I had another attribute in the "Hobbit" class: age = AttributeDescriptor("age"). Would that create another instance of "AttributeDescriptor" or would self.__attvalue be overwritten by this new attribute name ?

Comment: It will be a new one. -BTW you may just add prints to the class \__init__ method and see how much times it is called